# how slow down speed of UIPanGestureRecognizer in Monotouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

while i pan the image on single touch of gesture recognizer it moves image very fast how i can slow down the speed of UIPanGestureRecognizer my code is

```
void PanImage (UIPanGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer)
{
var image = gestureRecognizer.View;
if (gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began || gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed)
{
var translation = gestureRecognizer.TranslationInView (window);
gestureRecognizer.View.Center = new PointF (gestureRecognizer.View.Center.X + translation.X, gestureRecognizer.View.Center.Y + translation.Y);
gestureRecognizer.SetTranslation (PointF.Empty, image);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation you calculate from the recogniser can be divided by a factor to slow down the effect of the panning.

it can be done quite easily like this:

```
var factor =2;

gestureRecognizer.View.Center = new PointF (gestureRecognizer.View.Center.X + (translation.X/factor), gestureRecognizer.View.Center.Y + (translation.Y/factor));
```

Comment: taken aside that this probably is not the best way to achieve dragging an image around.